# @react-native-voice/voice doesn't detect speech services

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-voice

I'm trying to use @react-native-voice/voice to implement speech-to-text in my android RN app, I've tried using other variants of the package (like @react-native-community/voice and the deprecated @react-native-voice) but got the same results for all of them.
I can't use the package because my Voice.getSpeechRecognitionServices() is always empty, this results in any usage of the package not doing anything.
I tried checking the assistive app and it's Google, I tried switching it to Bixby, and then received `Error: Not allowed to bind to service Intent`
I also added the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission so I don't think that this is the issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from: https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice/issues/236

try adding this in your manifest file

```
<queries> <package android:name="com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"/> </queries>
```

Comment: same problem, but that didn't work for me ;p